# Python - seek in http response stream

Tags: python, http

Using `urllibs` (or `urllibs2`) and wanting what I want is hopeless.
Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'seek in http response stream'?

Comment: I once used C# and the implementation of what I talk about was like that: `WebClient.OpenRead().Seek()`.

Comment: A simple wrapper object can give you this functionality using the http range header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829311/is-there-a-library-for-retrieving-a-file-from-a-remote-zip/7852229#7852229

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure how the C# implementation works, but, as internet streams are generally not seekable, my guess would be it downloads all the data to a local file or in-memory object and seeks within it from there. The Python equivalent of this would be to do as Abafei suggested and write the data to a file or StringIO and seek from there.

However, if, as your comment on Abafei's answer suggests, you want to retrieve only a particular part of the file (rather than seeking backwards and forwards through the returned data), there is another possibility. `urllib2` can be used to retrieve a certain section (or 'range' in HTTP parlance) of a webpage, provided that the server supports this behaviour.

## The `range` header

When you send a request to a server, the parameters of the request are given in various headers. One of these is the `Range` header, defined in [section 14.35 of RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) (the specification defining HTTP/1.1). This header allows you to do things such as retrieve all data starting from the 10,000th byte, or the data between bytes 1,000 and 1,500.

## Server support

There is no requirement for a server to support range retrieval. Some servers will return the `Accept-Ranges` header ([section 14.5 of RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5)) along with a response to report if they support ranges or not. This could be checked using a HEAD request. However, there is no particular need to do this; if a server does not support ranges, it will return the entire page and we can then extract the desired portion of data in Python as before.

## Checking if a range is returned

If a server returns a range, it must send the `Content-Range` header ([section 14.16 of RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16)) along with the response. If this is present in the headers of the response, we know a range was returned; if it is not present, the entire page was returned.

## Implementation with urllib2

`urllib2` allows us to add headers to a request, thus allowing us to ask the server for a range rather than the entire page. The following script takes a URL, a start position, and (optionally) a length on the command line, and tries to retrieve the given section of the page.

```
import sys
import urllib2

# Check command line arguments.
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s url start [length]\n" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

# Create a request for the given URL.
request = urllib2.Request(sys.argv[1])

# Add the header to specify the range to download.
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    start, length = map(int, sys.argv[2:])
    request.add_header("range", "bytes=%d-%d" % (start, start + length - 1))
else:
    request.add_header("range", "bytes=%s-" % sys.argv[2])

# Try to get the response. This will raise a urllib2.URLError if there is a
# problem (e.g., invalid URL).
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# If a content-range header is present, partial retrieval worked.
if "content-range" in response.headers:
    print "Partial retrieval successful."

    # The header contains the string 'bytes', followed by a space, then the
    # range in the format 'start-end', followed by a slash and then the total
    # size of the page (or an asterix if the total size is unknown). Lets get
    # the range and total size from this.
    range, total = response.headers['content-range'].split(' ')[-1].split('/')

    # Print a message giving the range information.
    if total == '*':
        print "Bytes %s of an unknown total were retrieved." % range
    else:
        print "Bytes %s of a total of %s were retrieved." % (range, total)

# No header, so partial retrieval was unsuccessful.
else:
    print "Unable to use partial retrieval."

# And for good measure, lets check how much data we downloaded.
data = response.read()
print "Retrieved data size: %d bytes" % len(data)
```

Using this, I can retrieve the final 2,000 bytes of the Python homepage:

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ python retrieverange.py http://www.python.org/ 17387
Partial retrieval successful.
Bytes 17387-19386 of a total of 19387 were retrieved.
Retrieved data size: 2000 bytes
```

Or 400 bytes from the middle of the homepage:

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ python retrieverange.py http://www.python.org/ 6000 400
Partial retrieval successful.
Bytes 6000-6399 of a total of 19387 were retrieved.
Retrieved data size: 400 bytes
```

However, the Google homepage does not support ranges:

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ python retrieverange.py http://www.google.com/ 1000 500
Unable to use partial retrieval.
Retrieved data size: 9621 bytes
```

In this case, it would be necessary to extract the data of interest in Python prior to any further processing.

Answer (score 2):

It may work best just to write the data to a file (or even to a string, using [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html)), and to seek in that file (or string).

Comment: Let's say from a response of 1MB the first 900KB are useless for me, so it's an opportunity to speed up the process and not to download them.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any existing implementations of a file-like interface with seek() to HTTP URLs, so I rolled my own simple version: https://github.com/valgur/pyhttpio. It depends on `urllib.request` but could probably easily be modified to use `requests`, if necessary.

The full code:

```python
import cgi
import time
import urllib.request
from io import IOBase
from sys import stderr


class SeekableHTTPFile(IOBase):
    def __init__(self, url, name=None, repeat_time=-1, debug=False):
        """Allow a file accessible via HTTP to be used like a local file by utilities
         that use `seek()` to read arbitrary parts of the file, such as `ZipFile`.
        Seeking is done via the 'range: bytes=xx-yy' HTTP header.

        Parameters
        ----------
        url : str
            A HTTP or HTTPS URL
        name : str, optional
            The filename of the file.
            Will be filled from the Content-Disposition header if not provided.
        repeat_time : int, optional
            In case of HTTP errors wait `repeat_time` seconds before trying again.
            Negative value or `None` disables retrying and simply passes on the exception (the default).
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.name = name
        self.repeat_time = repeat_time
        self.debug = debug
        self._pos = 0
        self._seekable = True
        with self._urlopen() as f:
            if self.debug:
                print(f.getheaders())
            self.content_length = int(f.getheader("Content-Length", -1))
            if self.content_length < 0:
                self._seekable = False
            if f.getheader("Accept-Ranges", "none").lower() != "bytes":
                self._seekable = False
            if name is None:
                header = f.getheader("Content-Disposition")
                if header:
                    value, params = cgi.parse_header(header)
                    self.name = params["filename"]

    def seek(self, offset, whence=0):
        if not self.seekable():
            raise OSError
        if whence == 0:
            self._pos = 0
        elif whence == 1:
            pass
        elif whence == 2:
            self._pos = self.content_length
        self._pos += offset
        return self._pos

    def seekable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._seekable

    def readable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return not self.closed

    def writable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False

    def read(self, amt=-1):
        if self._pos >= self.content_length:
            return b""
        if amt < 0:
            end = self.content_length - 1
        else:
            end = min(self._pos + amt - 1, self.content_length - 1)
        byte_range = (self._pos, end)
        self._pos = end + 1
        with self._urlopen(byte_range) as f:
            return f.read()

    def readall(self):
        return self.read(-1)

    def tell(self):
        return self._pos

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if not object.__getattribute__(self, "debug"):
            return attr

        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def trace(*args, **kwargs):
                a = ", ".join(map(str, args))
                if kwargs:
                    a += ", ".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])
                print("Calling: {}({})".format(item, a))
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)

            return trace
        else:
            return attr

    def _urlopen(self, byte_range=None):
        header = {}
        if byte_range:
            header = {"range": "bytes={}-{}".format(*byte_range)}
        while True:
            try:
                r = urllib.request.Request(self.url, headers=header)
                return urllib.request.urlopen(r)
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
                if self.repeat_time is None or self.repeat_time < 0:
                    raise
                print("Server responded with " + str(e), file=stderr)
                print("Sleeping for {} seconds before trying again".format(self.repeat_time), file=stderr)
                time.sleep(self.repeat_time)
```

A potential usage example:

```python
url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/python-3.5.0-embed-amd64.zip"
f = SeekableHTTPFile(url, debug=True)
zf = ZipFile(f)
zf.printdir()
zf.extract("python.exe")
```

Edit: There is actually a mostly identical, if slightly more minimal, implementation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852229/2997179