# Unseekable HTTP Response

Tags: python, httpresponse, seek, mat-file

I am accessing some .mat files hosted on a SimpleHTTP server and trying to load them using Python's loadmat:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat    
import requests
r = requests.get(requestURL,stream=True)
print loadmat(r.raw)
```

However, I am getting an error

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

After looking around it seems that r.raw is a file object which is not seekable, and therefore I can't use loadmat on it. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984672/8334782) (modified slightly to work with Python 2.7), but maybe I did something wrong because when I try

```
seekfile = SeekableHTTPFile(requestURL,debug=True)
print 'closed', seekfile.closed
```

It tells me that the file is closed, and therefore I can't use loadmat on that either. I can provide the code for my modified version if that would be helpful, but I was hoping that there is some better solution to my problem here.

I can't copy/download the .mat file because I don't have write permission on the server where my script is hosted. So I'm looking for a way to get a seekable file object that loadmat can use.

**Edit: attempt using StringIO**

```
import StringIO
stringfile = StringIO.StringIO()
stringfile.write(repr(r.raw.read())) # repr needed because of null characters
loaded = loadmat(stringfile)
stringfile.close()
r.raw.close()
```

results in:

```
ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 48, 92
```

Comment: Can't you just use StringIO?

Comment: @PedroWerneck, I tried StringIO but loadmat does not recognize it as a .mat file and can't extract the data: `ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 48, 92`. I'll edit my question to include this.

Comment: @PedroWerneck, nevermind, you are right. I was mistakenly using `repr` on `r.raw.read()`